# How to check if a variable contains alphabetic characters but allow spaces?

Tags: php

```
(!ctype_alpha($director))
```

I am trying to use the ctype_alpha() function.

EG

```
if(!ctype_alpha($variable)) {
   The value entered contains other characters.
}
```

The problem with this approach is it won't allow a string with spaces. How do I make sure the user entered letters only, but allow for spaces (i.e, a name)?

Comment: You can try use this method `ctype_space`

Answer (score 2):

It depends a lot on what you call alphabetic, like: a-z? a-z á é ç? For the first you should use:

```
if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$variable)) {
}
```

For the second:

```
if (preg_match("/^[[:alpha:] ]*$/",$variable)) {
}
```

For more options you should check [PHP's PCRE manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php).

Comment: Using `*` would include nothing. We should also ask `@Anon Omus` if "contains", is the right word in his question, because using opening `^` and closing `$` would mean begins and ends with.

Comment: You are right, although the way you say it is a little confusing. The thing is: the current patterns let empty strings pass; @Anon Omus needs to change the "*" for "+" if he or she needs to rule out empty strings. I purposedly left this out of my example because it would add some complexity to the answer. You can keep digging: should a double space fail? Should a string beginning/ending with spaces fail?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
preg_match('/[a-zA-Z ]+/', $variable, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Actually,

```
function alphaSpace($string){
  return preg_match('/[a-zA-Z ]+/', $string) ? 1 : 0;
}
echo alphaSpace($someString) ? "It's a match!" : "It's not a match.";
```

, will just show you if there's a match. Of course, `$someString` would be a String of your choice.

Comment: This doesn't handle non-english character sets.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you've used `preg_match()`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be slow, but for small input streams not an issue, you can simply loop through the string one character at a time and check for !ctype_alpha( $c ) && ! ctype_space( $c ).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `function` just like my code. I use `str_replace` to remove the spaces before entering the `if else` condition. So, it will return `TRUE` if the `variable` contains alphabetic characters.

```
function check_string($var){

    $var = str_replace(' ', '', $var);

    if(ctype_alpha($var)){
      $result = TRUE;
    }
    else{
      $result = FALSE;
    }

    return $result;
  }
```

EG

```
if(check_string($var)) {
   TRUE IF VARIABLE CONTAINS ALPHABETIC CHARACTERS
}
```